# how i can open docx file using php docx?

Tags: php, docx, phpdocx

I am trying to open Docx file using phpdocx but I am getting this error.

```
function open_docx(){


`require_once 'phpdocx/classes/CreateDocx.';
$docx = new TransformDoc();
$docx->setStrFile('submitted/2794849631Aresha.docx');
$docx->generateXHTML();
$html = $docx->getStrXHTML();
}`
```

Fatal error: Class 'TransformDoc' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\uni\includes\functions.php on line 203

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

Comment: As the message says: Fatal error: Class 'TransformDoc' not found. You are calling a new class on your third line, but before you can do this, you have to implement this one.

Answer (score 0):

May be you forgot `.inc` in your require. Code may be like

```
function open_docx()
{
    require_once('phpdocx/classes/CreateDocx.inc');
    $docx = new TransformDoc();
    $docx->setStrFile('submitted/2794849631Aresha.docx');
    $docx->generateXHTML();
    $html = $docx->getStrXHTML();
}
```

Also you can try other libraries:
https://packagist.org/search/?q=docx&orderBys%5B0%5D%5Bsort%5D=downloads&orderBys%5B0%5D%5Border%5D=desc